# No module named libxml2 - Linux Mint Rafaela (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: python, linux, odoo, libxml2

I'm behind a virtualenv created with `virtualenvwrapper`

My problem is that I already installed everything I saw on any SO post.

Such as:

```
python-lxml
libxml2-dev 
libxslt-dev 
python-dev 
lib32z1-dev
zlib1g-dev
```

But nothing, I'm trying to install an odoo module which requires `libxml2` and still can't do it, it throws:

```
  File "/home/user/odoov8/odoo-venezuela/l10n_ve_withholding_islr/wizard/employee_income_wh.py", line 17, in <module>
import libxml2
ImportError: No module named libxml2
```

what can I do to run this?

I think it has something to do with virtualenvwrapper, but I'm not really sure.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `libxml2-dev` has only C/C++ files `*.h` to compile other tools which has to work with library `libxml2`. Real library is in `libxml2` - `apt search libxml2`, But it is C/C++ library and maybe you need also some `libxml2` Python module which works with `libxml2` C/C++ library.

Comment: I know, already installed most libraries, I think it has to do with virtualenv IMO

Comment: All of the libraries shown by apt search are installed in my system, also lxml by pip, ie: pip install lxml

Comment: in error message is `import libxml2` so it means it needs not only C/C++ library `libxml2` but also python module `libxml2` (not `lxml`). I checked `pip search libxml2` (on Linux Mint 17.3) and I see some modules but none with name `libxml2` - maybe one of this modules has file `libxml2.py` but I don't know which one.

Comment: I found `python-libxml2` in `apt`. After installation I can import `libxml2` in Python.

Comment: Hi, I have this on my system :(, I'm sorry, really, there is something more to it :/

Comment: as for me `python-libxml2` should resolve problem. Or maybe you have many Python version and you have installed `python-libxml2` in one version and it use different version. Maybe virtualenv is the real problem. `pip` should install in virtualenv (if it is active) but I'm not sure if `apt` works in virtualenv the same way.

Comment: Yep, it should be tested with virtualenv, however it is gone now that I've installed the system, system-wide, Thank You

Comment: The problem has to do with virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed  *python-libxml2*  using apt-get (or equivalent) you can access it inside virtualenv --system-site-packages flag

> virtualenv --system-site-packages env

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing the instance system-wide

However, I'll leave this question open if someone has a solution to work it out through virtualenv.

Thanks